# Fetch a fixed number of rows in SQL query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, informix

Please help me to write an SQL query in the Oracle database. There is table called tbl and it has 12 rows. I want to select first 4 rows first then next 4 and the last 4 rows.

Can any anyone tell me how can I do this in Informix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rownum`:

```
select * from (select t.*, rownum rn from tbl t) where rn between 1 and 4;
/
select * from (select t.*, rownum rn from tbl t) where rn between 5 and 8;
/
select * from (select t.*, rownum rn from tbl t) where rn between 9 and 12;
/
```

If you're using `order by` clause then use `row_number()` ([documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm))

```
select * from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by column_name) rn from tbl t) where rn between 1 and 4;
/
select * from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by column_name) rn from tbl t) where rn between 5 and 8;
/
select * from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by column_name) rn from tbl t) where rn between 9 and 12;
/
```

Comment: @yammy- Thanks, it works for me. Can you tell me how can I put where condition in the above query.

Comment: @AmitRaj You mean `where` for result filtering? You can add additional conditions after `where rn...` or inside subquery after `from tbl t where ...` (i recommend to put in inside subquery)

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: now should be fixed with 3-level select:

```
select * from (
  select q1.*, rownum as rn from (   --get correct rownum 
      select * from tbl order by column --get correct order
  ) q1
) q2
 where q2.rn between 1 and 4; -- filter
```

for first part.

For second and third part:

```
 where q2.rn between 5 and 8
 where q2.rn between 9 and 12
```

Comment: In your case `rownum between 5 and 8` and `rownum between 9 and 12` will not work, because values greater than positive integer are always false, as stated in [Oracle document](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm)

Comment: @vasja- yammy is right. it not working for second and third part.

Comment: ROWNUM doesn't work that way. ROWNUM beiing a pseudo-column, it will only increment further to 2 when it is at 1. So, when you say rownum between 5 and 8, ROWNUM doesn't even increment, so it will NEVER return any rows.

It will only work in this way :

`select * from(select rownum rn, val from order_test order by val) where rn between 5 and 8`

Comment: @vasja- yes, it is also working

Comment: You can simply use the query I posted in above comment :-)

Comment: @Latit - I believe you shouldn't use ORDER BY and ROWNUM in same query to get correct results because ROWNUM is avaluated BEFORE ordering of results (see http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ROWNUM). So shouldn't simplify like you proposed (though syntactically ok).

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing called as first rows, last rows, "n" rows unless you explicitly specify an ORDER BY and then select the required rows.

[Top-n Row Limiting](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqljoffsetfetch.html) feature in `Oracle 12c` on ward:

```
SQL> select * from order_test order by val;

       VAL
----------
         1
         1
         2
         2
         3
         3
         4
         4
         5
         5
         6
         6
         7
         7
         8
         8
         9
         9
        10
        10

20 rows selected.
```

**First 4 rows :**

```
SQL> SELECT val
  2  FROM   order_test
  3  ORDER BY VAL
  4  FETCH FIRST 4 ROWS ONLY;

       VAL
----------
         1
         1
         2
         2
```

**Next 4 rows(look at OFFSET)** :

```
SQL> SELECT val
  2  FROM   order_test
  3  ORDER BY VAL
  4  OFFSET 4 ROWS FETCH NEXT 4 ROWS ONLY;

       VAL
----------
         3
         3
         4
         4
```

**Finally, next 4 rows with OFFSET 8 rows :**

```
SQL> SELECT val
  2  FROM   order_test
  3  ORDER BY VAL
  4  OFFSET 8 ROWS FETCH NEXT 4 ROWS ONLY;

       VAL
----------
         5
         5
         6
         6
```

Comment: Nice to know that there's such feature in 12c!

Comment: It was there in MySql, now Oracle has it's own row Limiting Top N query feature.

No more worries and confusion with ROWNUM :-)