# ORA-00907:missing right parenthesis when taking sample from the data

Tags: sql, oracle, random

I want to take random sample by `id` (not by data points) from Oracle database. My code is shown below but it failed.

```
select C.* from original_table C, 
(select * from (select id from original_table group by id) as A 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 500) as B where C.id = B.id;
```

> error message is ORA-00907:missing right parenthesis, highlighting the
>   "as"s and the parenthesis "(select * " and "LIMIT 500) ".

Comment: I don't think `LIMIT 500` is valid Oracle database syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

- **RAND()** is not an Oracle function.

You could use **dbms_random** package.

- **LIMIT** is not supported in Oracle.

Alternatively, you could use following:

1. On 12c, you could use the new **[Top-n row limiting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25764049/3989608)** feature.
2. [**ROWNUM**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30321788/3989608) in pre-12c version..